# Odoo - How to update xml views and fields in database through command line

Tags: restart, odoo-10

I have created custom modules and the changes are not reflecting. What is the command to update these modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please mention your module name in the script parameters followed by "-u".

Example: `-u vendor_management`

this will update your module form the command line

Comment: I am new to Odoo, can you please share the script command.  I remember it to be something like "restart -u all" <- this will update all modules. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: /etc/init.d/odoo-server start -u module_name

Comment: /etc/init.d/odoo-server restart -u module_name

Answer (score 0):

When adding a custom addon a couple of things are necessary to have Odoo realise the changes in an addon or become alerted to the presence of a new addon.

Easiest way. Restart the server. Go to the apps section search for your app. Select it and update.

If you are really wanting a command line method. You can use erppeek and execute the following as admin.

```
model('ir.module.module').update_list()
client.upgrade('your_addon')
```

Or in an odoo shell you can execute.

```
env['ir.module.module'].update_list()
env['ir.module.module'].search([('name','=','your_addon')]).button_immediate_upgrade()
```

Or when starting your server you can append -u  to upgrade and addon at start up.

Odoo8 / Odoo9 Example

```
./odoo.py -d <your_db_name> -c <your_config_path> -u <your_addon>
```

Odoo10 Example

```
./odoo-bin -d <your_db_name> -c <your_config_path> -u <your_addon>
```